# Is "get away without" appropriate in this context?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

This is from [a news article](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/06/04/health/rectal-cancer-radiation-treatment.html) :

> “Now, especially, with patients skewing younger and younger, do they
> actually need radiation?” she asked. “Can we choose which patients can
> **get away without** this extremely toxic treatment that can lead to lifelong consequences, such as infertility and sexual dysfunction?”

I know '[get away with](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get-away-with?q=get%20away%20with)' is a phrasal verb meaning 'to manage with less of something than you might expect to need'.

Shouldn't "get away without" be replaced with 'get away with' in this context?

Comment: The treatment is what they (expect to) need, and less than a treatment is no treatment, so you might be able to *get away with no* treatment, or in other words, *get away without* it.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes it's correct.  You can't use "with" here. That would change the meaning significantly, almost to the exact opposite of the intended meaning.  To get away **without** this [treatment] means to escape the consequences of **not** having treatment.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, but more natural would be, "*“Can we choose which patients can get away **with not undergoing** this extremely toxic treatment...*"

Comment: @gotube Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link tells you that *get away with* has several meanings, variations on 'escape the serious consequences you might expect from doing something'. Here, some patients are expected to recover from cancer after *not* having radiation treatment - the 'doing something' in this case is 'not doing it'.

Comment: Thank you very much. You mean 'without' means '**not** doing it'. Right?

Comment: Yes. They can **get away without** it, that is, be cured by using other kinds of treatment.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.